# nginx 404 not found but I get hits in my access.log. Then why don't I see my site?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is tricky because it doesn't make sense. On the same server I have other sites that work just fine. The configuration file for each is the same. I created this new site, example.com and this is the configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/default/web;

}
```

I left the minimum in this file. 
I linked it, but when I go to the browser I get **404 Not Found**.

So in the root, I created a file `1.txt` just to check it on the browser. I still got 404.

I looked in the /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log and /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log and there was nothing. Then I looked at the general log, /var/log/nginx/access.log and I was getting this:

```
[21/Feb/2020:10:36:21 +0000] "GET /1.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"
```

So the request gets to the server but it's not reaching the root?

I made sure all permissions are directories 775 and files 774, users and groups are correct. 
I reloaded and also restarted nginx. 
I am out of ideas, I don't know what else is wrong. Can someone give me a hint?

UPDATE:
I have the ip of the server and the site in my `hosts` file because I don't have it on DNS yet. When I do `example.com` it's 404. When I look for `https://example.com` I see the `Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead`. I proceed and then  I see one of my other sites on the server. So there is a reason why the request is not going to the example.com but to another, even though I see it when I look for `nginx -T | grep server_name`.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the configuration that Nginx is actually reading. Clearly, Nginx is not using this `server` block, so it is either missing, a duplicate, you have a typo in the `server_name`, or you are not using `http` (port 80).

Comment: Yes, the site is there when i do `nginx -T | grep server_name`. So it's not that. Also, if I wasnt' using http then no other site on the server would be working.